# n-n relationship with an additional value for the same table in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, database-schema

I'm quite new to Laravel, and I'm trying to figure the correct way to design my database schema before starting anything.

So, here is the deal :

- I'm creating an application on which users should have to create an account. I'll need a `users` model/db table. No problem here.
- These users will be able to mention some of their friends. These friends should then be able to register and become legitimate users, or they won't.
- I wanted first to make two tables, but as the friends can become users as well, I thought adding them to the `users` table was quite logical (With something like a unregistered flag while they are not registered).

The catch is, I think Laravel is able to make automatically a correct n-n relationship between users and users, but I also wanted to allow the first users to add a pseudonym for their friends. In a "regular" database, I'd add the pseudonym field in the relationship database, but is it possible with Laravel, and how ?

After reading myself, I'm maybe not very self-explanatory. Si, here are the possible user stories :

- I create my account
- I mention my friend bob with his email, it creates a new user with only the email, and a relationship between me and bob in where I call him "friend"
- Alice creates her account, and mentions bob. It links her user account with bob's, but in the relashionship table she calls him "sweetie"
- Bob creates his account. Its users database entry is completed with his personal information / pseudonym, but Alice and I still see him as friend/sweetie

Sorry for being this talkative.

Comment: Have a good read here : https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many .. if you still stuck with something you can update your question

Comment: The pivots seem to do exactly what I wanted, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

You should do that as you mentioned.

1. Create a user table for all users - users are able to login, so it would be a good idea to use the base user model here.
2. Create a pseudonym table, which is 1:n - every user can give his frieds a new pseudonyn. But only 1 pseudonym for each friend, or? You could return his "user object" with the pseudonym if there is someone set, but only for me as usern. Use here Mutators: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-mutators
3. Create a n:n table where you connect UserIDs with UserIDs, showing ab here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships

I would really try to use Eloquent here, which makes it much more readable.